# Base class implements INotifyPropertyChanged : can derived types use its PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, refactoring, inotifypropertychanged

**EDIT**

From posters hints, I've found the following helpful links on MSDN:

[How to: Raise Base Class Events in Derived Classes (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx)

[Derived classes cannot raise base class events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecakwbz.aspx)

---

While refactoring I've come across an interesting question for which I haven't found an answer so far :

The refactoring consists of creating an `abstract` base class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, derived types would use it instead of implementing the interface themselves.

Can derived types use the base class event `PropertyChanged` or must they override it as shown below ?

If they must `override` it can you explain the reasons why it should be that way ?

(note: refactoring has been suggested by Resharper)

```
public abstract class BaseDTO : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ReviewDTO : BaseDTO
{
    private ImageSource _image;
    private string _summary;
    private string _url;

    public string Url
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _url) return;
            _url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Summary
    {
        get { return _summary; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _summary) return;
            _summary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _image)) return;
            _image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public override event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason (that I can think off) for the event itself to be virtual or overridden.

Comment: I've updated question with relevant links from MS that confirms your sayings, thanks everyone !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think they **must** override.

The base type can define a

> protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName);

The derived classes can just invoke the base method to trigger property notifications.

Just found some supporting evidence:
[MSDN page on implementing INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Of course, your base type can add more goodies

- like creating only one instance of event args per unique property name (less junk objects)
- inferring the name of the property via CallerMemberName
- using lambda expression form to flag incorrect property names

Comment: What do you mean by using a lambda expression form ?

Comment: See the post by bitbonk on this thread http://compositeextensions.codeplex.com/discussions/53731 on how to use lambda expressions for compile-time property name checks